# Can we lock just some string in Textbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

Somethings I want to do is initial value to text box and lock that string make it color to Gray.
and also user cann't change or delete it and cursor is activate next from it and then user can type any word from here
It's like a Tag but not
help Me
I use VB.NET2010

Comment: Do you mean like `ReadOnly`, or do you want something else?

Comment: I think he means the textbox itself is not read only but some part is. Like you have the value "Server" in it, grayed out and then you can type something after it, in the same textbox to make it for example ServerName or something. But the description is a lottle bit bogus. :-)

Comment: I meant two things above happen in the same textbox

Comment: AFAIK there is no way of doing this just out of the box. You can create two textboxes near to each other or you can check the content of the textbox using keyboard events and write back the original string if it is not present anymore, but you cannot change the color only part of the textbox. Maybe you can use richtextbox for this coloring.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
Private Sub txt_KeyDown(...) Handles txt.KeyDown
    If (txt.SelectionStart < 5 AND (e.KeyCode = Keys.Backspace OR e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete)) Then
        e.SuppressKey = true
    End If
End Sub
```

I have just given the logic and it is not complied solution. It may get some compiler error. but, you could do like this by assigning `SuppressKey` property to true when cursor location is withing a locking area and user presses Backspace or Delete key. it will not allow user to delete ur remove by backspace. You should also check ASCII value for [Ctrl+X]. So user cannot cut the text from there.